"Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite" error when building grpc in android kotlin
I am getting started with grpc + kotlin (android). I am trying to build a simple HelloWorld app but getting following error when trying to build the app:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-java-3.25.3.jar -> protobuf-java-3.25.3 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.25.3) and protobuf-javalite-3.25.5.jar -> protobuf-javalite-3.25.5 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.25.5)

My app build.gradle:
import com.google.protobuf.gradle.*

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.protobuf")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.13"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:4.29.0"
    }
    plugins {
        id("java") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.69.0"
        }
        id("grpc") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.69.0"
        }
        id("grpckt") {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.4.1:jdk8@jar"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach {
            it.plugins {
                id("java") {
                    option("lite")
                }
                id("grpc") {
                    option("lite")
                }
                id("grpckt") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
            it.builtins {
                id("kotlin") {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.15.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.8.7")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.3")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.12.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.0")
    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.25.3")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.69.0")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.62.2")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.69.0")

    implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.25.3")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.4.1")
    implementation("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.69.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.12.01"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}

My project's build.gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.7.3" apply false
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.9.4" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.23" apply false
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.9.4")
    }
}

I tried following several references like:

Setting up Protobuf + Kotlin in Android Studio 2023
https://github.com/wilsoncastiblanco/notes-grpc/tree/master

But no luck!
